# Jquery mouse over adding css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a p tag inside an anchor, there many be a variable number of instances of this during the loop. My goal is to on hover make the p tag expand and show more information. I have this so far in terms of `mouseover`.

however this is not working for me. does anyone have any ideas how to achieve this? someonehow i need to use the passed parameter `'e'` to change the height

`boxOPToneplustwo` : this is an a tag as well.

```
$('.boxOPToneplustwo').mouseover(function (e) {
    console.log("in");
    $(e.target).next('p').addClass("popupHighlight");
});
```

element creation:

```
anchorElement = "<a id='anchor" + countWide + "' class=\"boxOPToneplustwo\" alt=\'"+ image_website +"' style=\"cursor:pointer;width:"+ itemWidth + "px"+";height:"+anchorHeight+";position:absolute;left:"+ locationLeft + "px"+";top:0.3%;\" ><p id=\"test\" class=\"popupDynamic\"> " + popupImageTitles[i] + "</p>";
        anchorElement += '</a>';
```

Comment: To confirm it is the p tag's css i want to change, thanks

Comment: If the `p` tag is inside the anchor, wouldn't the target most likely already be the `p` tag, and you should really be using `$('p', this).addClass('popupHighlight')`

Comment: Hey guys. adeneo suggestion solves the probem. your effort is very appreciated :) want to get out of work asap today, christmas eve!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with jQuery you can use `this` to refer to the handled element.

```
$('.boxOPToneplustwo').mouseover(function (e) {
    console.log("in");
    $(this).next('p').addClass("popupHighlight");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

**Console play**
e.g: trying putting the following code in the console (F12) and see what it does to SO :P

```
 $("p, span").mouseover(function(){ $(this).css("display", "none"); } );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it still does not solve the problem. EDIT: i will try your new suggestion

Comment: is the `<p>` element located *after* the `.boxOPToneplustwo`? see http://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: I will update my answer with the line of code creating the p and a elements.